# How should I concretely see that the second homology of a punctured torus is trivial.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

By the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, one can calculate that if $T^*$ is a punctured torus, then $H_2(T^*,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

Concretely, what this means is that either there are no singular 2-cycles. How can I explicitly "see" that every singular 2-chain has a nonzero boundary?

Comment: Punctured means that you delete a point? Anyway, there are no 3-chains. You need to show that there are no 2-cycles.

Comment: @PeterFranek Thanks, I've edited the question.

Comment: It doesn't mean that there are no $2$-cycles; it means that they are all boundaries.

Answer (score 4):

You can see a torus as  the quotient of the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and identifying $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ to $[0,1]\times \{1\}$ and $\{0\}\times [0,1]$ to $\{1\}\times [0,1]$. If you remove a point in the middle of the square and you make the quotient, it retracts to have a bouquet of 2 circles whose second homology group is zero.